# Tag words should be hyphenated

Tags: support, tags

We already have two tags [freedomofspeech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedomofspeech) and [criminallaw](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criminallaw) that were created without the traditional hyphen-delimiting of words.  Who can fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I didn't notice this on Meta. I already fixed these when I ran across them as I was browsing around on the main site.

But a reminder to everyone that they should replace spaces with hyphens is useful. Tags are so much easier to read when hyphenated.